# Delay before the file transfer on Linux or Solaris

Tags: linux, file, delay, solaris, transfer

I would like to put delay before file transfer on Linux or Solaris.

As far as i know scp commands has no delay option.

> **scp file_name root@dest_ip:/dest_path**

So, how can i put delay (it can change between 250ms and 500ms)?

Comment: Try asking on [su]. Your question is not about software development and thus of-topic here, see: [help/on-topic]

Comment: i have just moved this question to superuser http://superuser.com/questions/781793/delay-before-the-file-transfer-on-linux-or-solaris

Answer (score 0):

You can run a command `at` a specific time.
See eg [here](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_at.htm)

```
at 1200 
scp file_name root@dest_ip:/dest_path
```

However, there may be better approaches - for example, if you are waiting for a file to be ready.